# html5 video source mp4 file

Tags: html, video, embed, filesize

I'm wondering what is the recommended max filesize for an background .mp4 movie

```
    <video>
      <source src='vids/mymovie.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
```

Normally I use vimeo or youtube and embed it, but in this example I has to use the video source way

my test movie was 10MB but the movie I received is 400mb big, won't I overload my hosting that way?